# GEKKO "Memory allocation failed"

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I'm trying to use [GEKKO](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to solve quite a large optimization problem locally (with `remote=False`).

When running the code, I get the error:

```
Error: At line 463 of file custom.f90
Traceback: not available, compile with -ftrace=frame or -ftrace=full
Operating system error: Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.

Memory allocation failed
```

So that hints that the operating system doesn't let GEKKO use enough memory.

However, I'm using a 32GB RAM machine, with nearly 25 GB free, while the model probably don't even need 10GB.

I've tried using `m.options.MAX_MEMORY = 10`, but this doesn't seem to matter.

> **Any thoughts on how to allow it to allocate more memory?**

Here is some (simplified) code that triggers this error:

```
from gekko import GEKKO

quantiles = [(x+1)*.01 for x in range(300)]

#Initialize Model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
#Set global options
m.options.IMODE = 3 #steady state optimization    
m.options.SOLVER=3
m.options.MAX_ITER=100000
m.options.MAX_MEMORY = 10
m.options.REDUCE=10

#initialize variables
Est_array = m.Array(m.Var,(2, 16),value=1,lb=0,ub=48)
P_ij_t = m.Array(m.Var,(4, 16, 300), lb=0, ub=1)   
Exp_ij_t = m.Array(m.Var,(4, 16, 300),value=1,lb=-36,ub=36)   
C_t = m.Array(m.Var,300,lb=0,ub=5) 

#Equations
for h in range(16): 
    for q in range(300):
        m.Equation(m.sum([P_ij_t[i,h,q] for i in range(3)]) == 1)

for (q,t) in enumerate(quantiles):
    m.Equation(C_t[q] == (  m.sum([P_ij_t[i+2,h,q]*(Est_array[i,h]-t)**2 for i in range(2) for h in range(16)]) + \
                            m.sum([P_ij_t[i,h,q]*(Est_array[1-i,15-h]-t)**2 for i in range(2) for h in range(16)]) 
    )  
    )
   
#Objective
m.Minimize(C_t[0])

#Solve simulation
#m.open_folder() 
m.solve()

#Results
print('C = ' + str(C_t[0].value[0]))
```

---

(All of the `m.options.*` parameters are things that I tried to get the solver to run, but none seem to help with the memory allocation problem).

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: @JohnHedengren - Windows 10.

Comment: @JohnHedengren - the problem seems to go away if I run the same model on a Linux VM on the same machine. Any ideas why this happens in Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows binary is 32-bit while the Linux, MacOS, and ARM Linux are 64-bit executables when `remote=False` with Gekko `v1.0.2`. With `remote=True`, it runs on a Linux server that has 64 GB of RAM and uses a 64-bit executable. It is running into a memory limit issue with the Windows binary up to 4 GB RAM because of the 32-bit executable. The 64-bit executables have a 16 billion GB capacity (no limit). The 64-bit Windows local executable is a planned development with a future release. The Linux VM or an [APM Linux server](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/APMonitorServerLinux) (such as host IP `10.0.0.10`) are options for those who need to solve large problems on a Local Network with a Windows local gekko client.

```py
m = GEKKO(remote=True, server='https://10.0.0.10')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. 
Could you kindly update when a 64-bit Windows executable is released? Running Gekko inside of a Linux VM is not catastrophic, but it does seem to be ~1.7 times slower.

Comment: Yes, I'll add information to the CHANGELOG.md file at https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md as it is updated.